# How can bash script do the equivalent of Ctrl-C to a background task?

Tags: bash

Is there any way to invoke a subprocess so that it and all its descendants are sent an interrupt, just as if you Ctrl-C a foreground task? I’m trying to kill a launcher script that invokes a long-running child. I’ve tried `kill -SIGINT $child` (which doesn’t send the interrupt to its descendants so is a no-op) and `kill -SIGINT -$child` (which works when invoked interactively but not when running in a script).

Here’s a test script. The long-running script is `test.sh --child`. When you call `test.sh --parent`, it invokes `test.sh --child &` and then tries to kill it. How can I make the parent kill the child successfully?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "--child" ]; then
sleep 1000

elif [ "$1" = "--parent" ]; then
"$0" --child &
for child in $(jobs -p); do
  echo kill -SIGINT "-$child" && kill -SIGINT "-$child"
done
wait $(jobs -p)

else
echo "Must be invoked with --child or --parent."
fi
```

I know that you can modify the long-running child to `trap` signals, send them to its subprocess, and then wait (from 
[Bash script kill background (grand)children on Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696691/bash-script-kill-background-grandchildren-on-ctrlc)), but is there any way without modifying the child script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this : [How to send a signal SIGINT from script to script ? BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524937/how-to-send-a-signal-sigint-from-script-to-script-bash)

Also from `info bash`

```
   To facilitate the implementation of the user interface to job  control,
   the operating system maintains the notion of a current terminal process
   group ID.  Members of this process group (processes whose process group
   ID is equal to the current terminal process group ID) receive keyboard-
   generated signals such as SIGINT.  These processes are said  to  be  in
   the  foreground.  Background processes are those whose process group ID
   differs from the terminal's; such processes are immune to keyboard-gen‐
   erated signals.
```

So `bash` differentiates background processes from foreground processes by the *process group ID*. If the *process group id* is equal to *process id*, then the process is a foreground process, and will terminate when it receives a `SIGINT` signal. Otherwise it will not terminate (unless it is trapped).

You can see the *process group Id* with

```
ps x -o  "%p %r %y %x %c "
```

Thus, when you run a background process (with `&`) from within a script, it will ignore the `SIGINT` signal, unless it is trapped.

However, you can still kill the child process with other signals, such as `SIGKILL`, `SIGTERM`, etc.

For example, if you change your script to the following it will successfully kill the child process:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "--child" ]; then
  sleep 1000
elif [ "$1" = "--parent" ]; then
  "$0" --child &
  for child in $(jobs -p); do
    echo kill "$child" && kill "$child"
  done
  wait $(jobs -p)

  else
  echo "Must be invoked with --child or --parent."
fi
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh --parent
kill 2187
./test.sh: line 10:  2187 Terminated              "$0" --child
```

Answer (score 19):

For anyone wondering, this is how you launch childs in the background and kill them on ctrl+c:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
command1 &
pid[0]=$!
command2 &
pid[1]=$!
trap "kill ${pid[0]} ${pid[1]}; exit 1" INT
wait
```

Comment: This is useful, although I found that `kill` would only kill the processes specified in the arguments, and not their descendants.

Answer (score 7):

```
somecommand &
```

returns a pid of the child in `$!`

```
somecommand &
pid[0]=$!
anothercommand &
pid[1]=$!
trap "kill ${pid[0]} ${pid[1]}; exit 1" INT
wait
```

I would start with this model rather than with bash job control (bg, fg, jobs).  Normally init inherits and reaps orphan processes.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I realize that I can modify the child script to pass interrupts on to the processes that it spawns. I was just wondering whether it’s possible to send interrupts to descendants without modifying the child script.

Comment: FYI: Line 2 should have a $! not $1

Comment: INT did not work for me, I used EXIT instead on OS X

Answer (score 3):

You can keep using `SIGINT` with background tasks with an easy little twist: Put your asynchronous subprocess call in a function or `{` `}`, and give it `setsid` so it has its own process group.

Here's your script keep it's whole first intention:

- using and propagating `SIGINT` and not using another signal
- modifying only the calling from: `"$0" --child &` to `{ setsid "$0" --child; } &`
- adding the code necessary to get the PID of your child instance, which is the only process in the background subshell.

Here's your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "--child" ]; then
sleep 1000

elif [ "$1" = "--parent" ]; then
{ setsid "$0" --child; } &
subshell_pid=$!
pids=$(ps -ax -o ppid,pid --no-headers |
    sed -r 's/^ +//g;s/ +/ /g' |
    grep "^$subshell_pid " | cut -f 2 -d " ");
for child in $pids;  do
  echo kill -SIGINT "-$child" && kill -SIGINT "-$child"
done
wait $subshell_pid

else
echo "Must be invoked with --child or --parent."
```

**Here's the important doc part from bash manual**

Process group id effect on background process (in *Job Control* section of doc):

> [...] processes whose process group ID is equal to the current terminal
>   process group ID [..] receive keyboard-generated signals such as
>   SIGINT.  These processes are said  to  be  in the  foreground. 
>   **Background processes** are those whose process group ID  differs from
>   the terminal's; such processes **are immune to keyboard-generated
>   signals**.

Default handler for `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` (in *Signals* section of doc):

> Non-builtin commands run by bash have signal handlers set to the values inherited  by  the  shell  from its parent.  When job control is not in effect, **asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT** in addition to these  inherited handlers.

and about modification of traps (in `trap` builtin doc):

> **Signals  ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset**.