# Sending signals to a linux process and intercepting them

Tags: linux, bash, process, signals

I have a following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..8}
do
  trap "echo received $i" $i
done
trap "echo 'receiving the SIGINT'; kill -9  $$" INT
for i in {10..64}
do
  trap "echo receiving the $i" $i
done

sleep 1h
```

If run it and from other terminal send the SIGINT to it, it does nothing.
I am using `kill -2 pid` where pid is the pid of the running script.

If I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (SIGINT) in terminal where the script is running it kills itself and writes the message. How come, it is not the same when sending the signal to it from a different terminal?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696427/how-can-bash-script-do-the-equivalent-of-ctrl-c-to-a-background-task/14697034#14697034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I replace the `sleep 1h` with the

```
while true ; do
    sleep 1
done
```

It is working :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the shell delivers handled signals ("springs a *trap*") [only between commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11).  This means that your script's INT *trap* cannot spring until the child *sleep* process has exited.

In the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> case, [the terminal sends a SIGINT to the foreground process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09).  This group includes both *your_script.sh* and its child *sleep 1h*.  The child process is killed immediately, and then the script unblocks and springs the *trap* for the signal it received, too.

In the *kill -INT* case, the SIGINT is delivered only to *your_script.sh* but not to its child, so the `trap` is held pending until the child exits normally.  That's why reducing the *sleep* interval from 1 hour to a tight loop of 1 second periods works:  the *trap* is pending for no more than 1 second.