# cannot trap SIGINT signal for bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, sigint, sigterm

I have a script that calls

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_trap(){
  echo "signal was trapped";
}

trap my_trap INT
trap my_trap SIGINT
echo "here is the pid: $$"
echo "here is the parent id just in case: $(ps -o ppid= -p $$)"
tsc --watch # open a server / watch process
```

I call that script in terminal window 1. In another terminal window (terminal 2) I call

```
kill -INT <pid>
```

I call that for both the pid and parent pid echoed in the other terminal

nothing gets trapped - nothing gets logged ("signal was trapped" does not get logged)..

anyone know why SIGINT cannot be caught? **Note that if I use ctrl-c in terminal 1, it does get caught, so something about sending SIGINT from another terminal window is not working.**

Comment: Read [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

Comment: oh no that sounds no bueno lol

Comment: looks very good, but for other users short on time - is there any way to send a SIGINT signal to another process and trap it?

Comment: Consider using some other signal, perhaps  `SIGUSR1`; read about  [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group)s

Comment: thanks I see, this seems to relate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668841/send-signal-between-scripts-bash

Comment: yeah I am trying to trap SIGUSR1 in the first script, and send that signal from the second sibling script, not sure if it will work, not working so far

Comment: BTW, signals are the worst [inter process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facility. Why don't you design your code to use something better?

Comment: this is pure bash code, for a library that's just written in bash, so, if you have a better idea, I am all for it

Comment: SIGUSR1 is sorta working, but I am getting this error: `Bus error: 10` looks like a lower level C related error

Comment: I guess I could set up a single named pipe and then each instance read from it, and it will received PIDs, and if the current script PID equals the next PID coming down the pipe I could do something

Comment: yeah named pipe won't work, because multiple processes will be writing to it and yeah that can't be handled easily / can't be multi-plexed...honestly IPC on most computers f*cking sucks...no wonder people tend to use network protocols instead...