# Kill background process on SIGINT

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, dash-shell

I have this script, which should start a keep-alive script and Sublime Text 3 under Bash for Windows:

```bash
#!/bin/dash

set -e

# Keep alive (in background)
tail -f /dev/null &
pid=$!

echo "tail process id: ${pid}"
echo "Keep-alive process started with Sublime Text 3\nPress SIGINT (CTRL+C) to kill it..."

# Start Sublime Text 3
DISPLAY=localhost:0 /usr/bin/sublime

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/19274804/1442219
trap "kill ${pid}; exit 1" INT
wait
```

This code generates:

```
tail process id: 49
Keep-alive process started with Sublime Text 3
Press SIGINT (CTRL+C) to kill it...
tail: cannot determine location of '/dev/null'. reverting to polling: Invalid argument
```

The whole purpose of this script that I run Sublime Text 3 with GUI with Xorg server under Bash for Windows. I try to make a shortcut to start this script with `"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "./my-script.sh"` command and Bash for Windows have to run in the background when I use ST3, because otherwise there are `dbus` errors (even if you modified `/etc/dbus-1/session.conf`)

The problem is: If I press `CTRL+C`, `tail` process is still presented in the background.

**Edit:**

I changed the ordering in the script, putted `tail` and `wait` under everything.

**Solved:**

Looks like `dash` isn't supporting `SIGINT` or `INT`. Solution is to use `bash` and `SIGINT` will work as it should.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I kill background processes / jobs when my shell script exits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits)

Comment: Your `wait` command causes the script to pause and wait for all background jobs to be finished.  So your `tail` command has to finish before the `sublime` command is launched.  Is that your intent?  As for the problem with `tail`, maybe you could try using `sleep` with a very long duration?

Comment: No, `tail` command proves that `Bash for Windows`, aka Linux Subsystem for Win10 should run in the background parallel with ST3, because of `dbus` issues. If you close ST3, that's souldn't effect this script, at least this not what I intend to do on the first place.

Comment: Looks like `dash` isn't supporting `SIGINT` or `INT`. Solution is to use `bash` and `SIGINT` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `dash` isn't supporting `SIGINT` or `INT` (at least this is the case in the Linux subsystem for Windows). Solution is to use `bash` and `SIGINT` will work as it should.

sublime.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Just to make sure, this line takes PID1 in Docker environments
# So SIGINT/SIGKILL won't be blocked
echo "pid1" > /dev/null

echo -e "\n///////////////////////////////////////////////\n"

# Keep alive (in background) hack from Docker environments
tail -f /dev/null &
pid[0]=$!

echo "tail process id: ${pid[0]}"
echo -e "Keep-alive process started with Sublime Text 3\nPress SIGINT (CTRL+C) to kill it..."

# Start Sublime Text 3
DISPLAY=localhost:0 /usr/bin/sublime

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/19274804/1442219
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/360275/1442219
trap "kill ${pid[0]}; exit 1" SIGINT

echo -e "\n///////////////////////////////////////////////\n"

wait
```

sublime.cmd

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "./sublime.sh"
```

Comment: This is really intersting.  Is it possible to do something similar without the display of sublime (eg in a CI environment)?